# Notify a directive about data receiving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have this simple angular directive:

```
angular.module("directives").directive("loading", function($rootScope) {

   return {
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

         console.log("loading directive", scope, element, attrs);

         element.addClass("hidden");

         $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
            element.removeClass("hidden");
         });

         // how do I notify data have been received in the controller? <---
      }
   };
});
```

As you can see it allows me to show a loading message to be displayed when the route of the app changes. Like this:

Loading...

**My problem is that I dunno how to notify the directive in order to get it to disappear.**

Let's say the route `/list/` is associated to `ListController`. When the url `/list/` gets hit, the controller will load some data and only when such data have been received I would like the loading message to go away. Clearly the directive have no idea when the controller's data gets delivered so my question remains:

How the heck do I come up with a decent design for this?

Comment: Try to $broadcast event and catch it in directive

Answer (score 0):

To basically simplify the design and structure it in a way, what I do is have a 'messaging' service defined as part of an Angular module that takes care of this. Whenever there's a route change, it sets its most current message to 'Loading…' and when a controller is finished loading (finishes all Ajax requests, for example), it calls a `clear()` on the messaging service to clear all recent messages.

In your directive (in my case a navbar), you can watch for `latestMessages` from your messaging service and change the alert depending on what the `latestMessage` changes to. If its blank, you clear the message and so forth.

A little more work, I guess, but its a lot more structured and modular this way. Plus, since the messaging service is central, it can accept messages from as many modules as you'd want.